# How does tfidf transform test data after being fitted to train data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am using the following code:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', 
                      TfidfVectorizer( ngram_range=(1,2),
                                       stop_words="english", 
                                       sublinear_tf=True ,
                                       use_idf=True, 
                                       norm='l2' )),
                     ('reduce_dim',
                      SelectPercentile(f_classif, 90)),
                     ('clf', 
                      SVC(kernel='linear',C=1.0, 
                          probability=True, max_iter=70000, 
                          class_weight='balanced'))])

model = pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.predict(X_test)

x=vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_text)
y=vectorizer.transform(X_test_text)
```

As per my understanding, `pipeline.fit()` fits tfidf to the train data and when `model.predict()` is called on `X_test`, it only does a tfidf transformation based on the fitted train data.

Since tf idf works by getting frequency of words in the document and corpus, I am wondering what happens underneath in the `.fit_transform` and `.transform` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) pretty close to your question you can find here:[What is the difference between TfidfVectorizer.fit_transfrom and tfidf.transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027864/what-is-the-difference-between-tfidfvectorizer-fit-transfrom-and-tfidf-transform)

2)tfidf transformation is done inside of `fit-transform`, `predict` here doesn't correspond to tfidf vectorizer, as it doesnt have such a function, it is method of SVC.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit) is the basic documentation of `fit()` and `fit_transform()`.

Your understanding of the working is correct. When testing the parameters are set for the `tf-idf Vectorizer`. These parameters are stored and used later to just transform the testing data.

- Training data - `fit_transform()`
- Testing data - `transform()`

If you want to look at the inside workings, you should have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1618) for the same.