# What could be the reason for the "transform not found" AttributeError in scikit-learn's CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

**Libraries used:**

```
import random
import numpy as np
import nltk
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
```

**Installed libraries:**

```
python -m pip freeze  # to see all packages installed in the active virtualenv

beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
distlib==0.3.6
filelock==3.9.0
Flask==2.2.3
fonttools==4.38.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.2.0
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.7.0
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.24.2
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
Pillow==9.4.0
pipenv==2023.2.18
platformdirs==3.0.0
psutil==5.9.4
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7.1
regex==2022.10.31
requests==2.28.2
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
sklearn==0.0.post1
soupsieve==2.4
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tqdm==4.64.1
urllib3==1.26.14
virtualenv==20.19.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
Werkzeug==2.2.3
```

**Block of code with the error:**

```
def get_intent(text, vectorizer):
    text_vect = vectorizer.transform([preprocess(text)])
    sim_scores = cosine_similarity(text_vect, vectorizer)
    intent = intents.keys()
    index = np.argmax(sim_scores)
    if sim_scores[0][index] < 0.5:
        return 'Não entendi'
    else:
        return list(intent)[index]
```

[Error appearing in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpSbm.png)

**Complete code up to the error:**

```
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')

intents = {
    'saudacao': ['Olá', 'Oi', 'E aí', 'Olá, como posso ajudá-lo?'],
    'adeus': ['Tchau', 'Até logo', 'Até a próxima vez', 'Tchau, tenha um bom dia!'],
    'agradecimento': ['Obrigado', 'Muito obrigado', 'Obrigado por sua ajuda', 'Agradeço sua ajuda'],
    'informacao': ['Qual é o seu nome?', 'O que você pode fazer?', 'Qual é a sua função?', 'O que você é?']
}


def preprocess(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = lemmatizer.lemmatize(text)
    return text


vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit_transform([' '.join(intent) for intent in intents.values()])

def get_intent(text, vectorizer):
    text_vect = vectorizer.transform([preprocess(text)])
    sim_scores = cosine_similarity(text_vect, vectorizer)
    intent = intents.keys()
    index = np.argmax(sim_scores)
    if sim_scores[0][index] < 0.5:
        return 'Não entendi'
    else:
        return list(intent)[index]
```

**Requested information:**

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033185/610569, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fit_transform` returns an array. You should use `fit` instead:

```py
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit([' '.join(intent) for intent in intents.values()])
```